# With StripeClient I got error No API key provided

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

in my Laravel 8 / with stripe/stripe-php": "^7.75" I try to connect and create account on stripe side
and got error :

```
 No API key provided. Set your API key when constructing the StripeClient instance, or provide it on a per-request basis using the `api_key` key in the $opts argument.
```

with code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Stripe;
use Stripe\StripeClient;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

use App\Models\Settings;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\StripeToken;

class SellerController extends Controller
{
    protected StripeClient $stripeClient;
    protected DatabaseManager $databaseManager;
    public function __construct(StripeClient $stripeClient, DatabaseManager $databaseManager)
    {

        \Log::info(varDump($stripeClient, ' -1 SellerController ::'));
        $this->stripeClient = $stripeClient;
        $this->databaseManager = $databaseManager;
    }

    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        \Log::info('-1 showProfile $id ::' . print_r($id, true));
        $seller = User::find($id);
        if (!$seller) {
            abort(404);
        }
        return view('market.seller', [
            'seller' => $seller,
            'balance' => null
        ]); // /_wwwroot/lar/tAdsBack/resources/views/admin/stripe/stripe.blade.php

    } // public function showProfile($id)

    public function redirectToStripe($id)
    {
        \Log::info('-1 redirectToStripe $id ::' . print_r($id, true));
        $seller = User::find($id);
        if (!$seller) {
            abort(404);
        }
        $appEnv = strtolower(config('app.env'));

        if ($appEnv == 'local' or $appEnv == 'dev') {
            \Log::info('-1 config(app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY)::' . print_r(config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY'), true));
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY')); // LOOKS LIKE THAT IS NOT APPLIED
            $this->stripeClient->apiKey = config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY'); // THIS DOES NOT HELP
            $this->stripeClient->api_key = config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY');  // THIS DOES NOT HELP
        }
        if ($appEnv == 'production') {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('app.STRIPE_LIVE_KEY'));
            $this->stripeClient->opts['api_key'] = config('app.STRIPE_LIVE_KEY');
        }


        if (!$seller->completed_stripe_onboarding) { // Complete onboarding process
            $str = \Str::random();
            $stripeToken = new StripeToken();
            $stripeToken->token =  $str;
            $stripeToken->seller_id =  $id;
            $stripeToken->save();


            if (empty($seller->stripe_connect_id)) {  // if has no stripe account
                // // Create a new Stripe Connect Account object.
                \Log::info('-1 $$this->stripeClient ::' . print_r($this->stripeClient, true));
```

Checking log I see :

```
[2021-03-22 05:40:30] local.INFO: -1 $$this->stripeClient ::Stripe\StripeClient Object
(
    [coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient:private] => 
    [config:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Array
        (
            [api_key] => 
            [client_id] => 
            [stripe_account] => 
            [stripe_version] => 
            [api_base] => https://api.stripe.com
            [connect_base] => https://connect.stripe.com
            [files_base] => https://files.stripe.com
        )

    [defaultOpts:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
        (
            [apiKey] => 
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [Stripe-Account] => 
                    [Stripe-Version] => 
                )

            [apiBase] => 
        )

    [api_key] => sk_test_NNNNNN
```

How to fix this error ?

I suppose I need to set api_key in some other way, not

```
$this->stripeClient->apiKey = config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY'); // THIS DOES NOT HELP
$this->stripeClient->api_key = config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY');  // THIS DOES NOT HELP
```

but how?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that `config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY')` isn't resolving to what you think it is. I'd log out that setting to make sure you're getting back a Stripe API key in the form of `sk_test_123`.

Comment: I have line with logging app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY
if ($appEnv == 'local' or $appEnv == 'dev') {
 \Log::info('-1 config(app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY)::' . print_r(config('app.STRIPE_TEST_KEY'), true));
  
and checking log file I see valid sk_test_NNN value in log line, but not inside of coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient object(I show it in my topic)

I did not catch idea with sk_test_123...

Answer (score -2):

Before using `stripe/stripe-php` directly, check out Laravel Cashier.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing

Comment: What have I to check ? different libs